# h:selectOneMenu value change listener is not fired

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I wounder the value change listener event is not fired. Also, I tried `f:valueChangeListener` and never get the event fired.

I'm using primefaces 5.3

Any Help, Please.

-- Here is the form

```
<h:form id = "templatelocal_id" name="templatelocal_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h:selectOneMenu 
                id="locale_menu_id" 
                value="#{localizationBean.selectedLocalName}"
                valueChangeListener="#{localizationBean.changeLanguage}"  
                onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItems 
                    var="c" 
                    value="#{localizationBean.localsList}"
                    itemLabel="#{c.displayLanguage}" 
                    itemValue="#{c.displayLanguage}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</h:form>
```

Here is the backing bean.

- List item

  ```
  @ManagedBean(name="localizationBean")
  @SessionScoped
  public class LocalizationBean {

     private Locale locale;

     private Locale selectedLocalName;

     private List<Locale> localsList = new ArrayList<Locale>();

     public LocalizationBean()
     {
         System.out.println("--------");
     }

     @PostConstruct
         public void init() 
         {
             System.out.println("--------Init");

             locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();

             localsList.add(locale);
             Iterator<Locale> lsList = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getSupportedLocales();

             while (lsList.hasNext()) {
                 Locale currentLocale = lsList.next();
                 localsList.add(currentLocale);
             }
         }

     public void changeLanguage(ValueChangeEvent e)
     {
         System.out.println("--------change");

         Object newValue = e.getNewValue();
         System.out.println("-----------" + newValue);
     }

     public Locale getLocale() 
     {
         return locale;
     }

     public String getLanguage() 
     {
         return locale.getLanguage();
     }

     public void setLanguage(String language) 
     {
         locale = new Locale(language);
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
     }

     public Locale getSelectedLocalName() {
         return selectedLocalName;
     }

     public void setSelectedLocalName(Locale selectedLocalName) {
         this.selectedLocalName = selectedLocalName;
     }

     public List<Locale> getLocalsList() {
         return localsList;
     }

     public void setLocalsList(List<Locale> localsList) {
         this.localsList = localsList;
     }

  }
  ```

Comment: What does `onchange="submit()"` do? And remove `primefaces` tag, there is no PrimeFaces in your code.

Comment: First of all have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/3736575). You are using a complex object type, adding a propper converter may help you.